# Browsing PC through phone with adb shell

Tags: adb, usb, linux, shell

I am connected to my phone from the laptop using wireless adb. After that, I connect my phone to laptop physically with a usb-wire. Now with the wireless adb-shell open, I want to find the wired "connection" and browse my pc through android-phone. (Like open a shared folder on the laptop with adb-shell)

Is that possible and if yes, how? (I want to replicate a similar scenario with my phone so I can connect it to my car-navigation system and browse through the system from my PC using adb-shell).

Comment: By adb you can copy files from the phone to your pc

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. ADB is a one-way channel. Excerpt from [help](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html):

> When you start an adb client, the client first checks whether there is
> an adb server process already running. If there isn't, it starts the
> server process. When the server starts, it binds to local TCP port
> 5037 and listens for commands sent from adb clients—all adb clients
> use port 5037 to communicate with the adb server.

To access PC you would have to set up an ADB server on your mobile device, which is currently impossible.

Comment: can you use adb shell without root?

Comment: yes, you can freely